# How do I increment a counter when clicking an item in an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have generated a list with ng-repeat, where each item has a count variable. In each list item I have a link.

I want to increment the count when I click the link.

I tried the following way but it not work.

My Controller :-

```
myApp.controller('allpost', function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, Allposts) {
    var id = $stateParams.id;
    Allposts.GetAllposts(id).then(
        function (response) {
            $scope.allPosts = response.data.posts;
        });

    function ctrl($scope) {
          $scope.increment = function(item){
            item.count += 1;
          }
        }
})
```

and view like :-

```
<ion-content class="padding" lazy-scroll>
<div class="row no-padding HomeRowsList">

<div class="item itemfull" ng-repeat="post in allPosts">
        <div class="item item-body">
            <div>
                <div class="title-news">
                    <div class="title" ng-bind-html="post.content"></div>
                    <div class="countbg">عدد المرات : {{post.custom_fields.azkarno}}</div>
                    <span>{{post.count}}</span><a onclick="ctrl(post);">Increment</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: You are not generating a *list*, you are generating a bunch of unsemantic, nested `div`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller use

```
$scope.increment = function(item){
    item.count += 1;
 };
```

instead of

```
function ctrl($scope) {
   $scope.increment = function(item){
     item.count += 1;
    }
}
```

and in  html use

```
<span>{{post.count}}</span><a data-ng-click="increment(post)">Increment</a>
```

instead of

```
<span>{{post.count}}</span><a onclick="ctrl(post);">Increment</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `ng-click` instead of `onclick` & the method name should be `increment` instead of `ctrl`.

Also remove unnecessary `ctrl` function wrapper from the `increment` method which is not needed at all, because whatever you wanted to call from the html should be included in the `$scope` of controller.

**Markup**

```
<span>{{post.count}}</span><a ng-click="increment(post);">Increment</a>
```

Comment: @Android-wd is there any problem with mine answer?